# How to make AirDrop images save on all OS devices?

Tags: ios, photos, airdrop

Myself and my partner both have iPhones and usually take it in turns to take photos when we are together (so we do not end up with duplicates!). We then AirDrop them to each other's phones and they save in 'All Photos' on our iPhones.

Having recently bought a Mac and also owning an iPad, I have noticed that these photos do not sync into photos across all devices, even though they are connected using iCloud and would usually sync.

Is there a way to do this?

[image]

Comment: What are you using to "sync" the photos? iCloud Photo Library? Or are you just talking about Photo Stream?

Comment: All of my devices use iCloud and the photos normally sync when I open 'Photos'. For example, if I take a photo on my iPhone, when I open photos on my mac, they will be in there. This does not seem to be the case with airdropped photos that I have received, even though they show in the same photo stream as photos I have taken..

Comment: That's great, but do you have iCloud Photo Library enabled or is this just Photo Stream? Can you check Settings → Photos & Camera from your iPhone and [edit] your question with the state of the iCloud Photo Library and My Photo Stream options there?

Comment: I have added the image to my original question! Hope this helps!